# weighted power voronoi - power_diagramer.exe file

Tags: voronoi

As I understand in order to have power weighted voronoi diagram I need first to create/make file named:power_diagramer.exe as follow:
all:

- `#-frounding-math` is GCC specific, but required for any CGAL code compiled with GCC
- `g++ -O3 power_diagram_lib.cpp -o power_diagramer.exe -Wall -lCGAL -lgmp -lgmpxx -lmpfr -frounding-math`

1. my question is what are this line of code?
2. is it C++?
3. How can I run it and get the file?
4. also what is this file is it generated using CGAL library?

R,
Yaniv

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: You can try my php implementation:https://tetramatrix.github.io/awvd/

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: I have installed C++ compiler(MinGW) and ran:    g++ -O3 power_diagram_lib.cpp -o power_diagramer.exe -Wall -lCGAL -lgmp -lgmpxx -lmpfr -frounding-math
and the results:g++: error: power_diagram_lib.cpp: No such file or directory

Comment: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory

Comment: Does power_diagram.exe can be run on win 10 64 bit?Does 
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzgCF.png

Comment: @Yaniv Install php. Php works with W10.

Comment: @Yaniv Does it works?